# run shortcut file or exe file as administrator VBA

Tags: vba, admin, exe, shortcut

is it possible to run shortcut of some exe file through vba code?
or run exe file as administrator in same way?

I will be grateful for any tips,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but it is not directly possible. There is a thing called google. I think it was the first or second answer. You won't get more help as the rule applies: No code, no help.